# Python sqlite3 connection

Tags: python, database, sqlite

In my program there are multiple asynchronous functions updating data in a database.

There can be some cases where the functions are executed parallelly.

My question is :

- In my case, do I need to create a new connection each time in a function or having a single connection throughout the program will work fine.
- Second, in case of a single connection is it necessary to close it at the end?
- Also, please recommend the best tool to access .db file outside the code [Just in case], that shouldn't interrupt the connections of the code with the database even if I make some changes personally outside the code.

Note : Am on windows

Thanks!

Comment: If you are on MacOS, [Native SQLite Manager](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/native-sqlite-manager/id1416282836) is a good UI tool to read and update sqlite .db files.

Comment: Mixing asynchronous function calls with synchronous db calls will not give you any benefit of using asyncio. You will have to make SQLite db calls asynchronously. See [aiosqlite](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/stable/)

Comment: Am a bit confused now, in case of asynchronous calls to the database, sqlite3 locks the database to prevent any data overwriting problems so what is the difference of using aiosqlite instead of sqlite3?

Comment: Plus am not just using asyncio for calling the database, those functions have stuff which needs asyncio functions like asyncio sleep and all, updating the database is just a part of the function.

Comment: It seems you are missing the point of using `asyncio`. When you make a call to a db, your program simply waits, doing nothing till it receives response from the db. `asyncio` lets you do some work during this time instead of simply waiting. To do asynchronous calls, you have to use `aiosqlite`. You may want to read some tutorials/docs on what problem does asyncio tries to solve.